# OutOfMemory when placing a beans.xml file into the META-INF dir

Tags: java, memory-management, glassfish

I am having a maven driven application, which runs beans in glassfish. Now I want to inject my beans, and therefore I need a beans.xml in place. But when I am placing the file into the META-INF dir, I am getting errors on deploy:

```
Information: WELD-000900 SNAPSHOT
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:07 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.parser.JAXPParser : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:07 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.parser.XSOMParser$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:08 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.parser.XSOMParser : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:08 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.ComponentNameFunction : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:15 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.ContextClassloaderLocal$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:25 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.ContextClassloaderLocal : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:26 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.DeferedCollection$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:26 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.DeferedCollection : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:27 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.DomAnnotationParserFactory$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:27 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.DomAnnotationParserFactory$AnnotationParserImpl : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:33 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.DomAnnotationParserFactory : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:43 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.NameGetter : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:49:54 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.SimpleTypeSet : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:06 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.TypeClosure : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:16 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.TypeSet$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:27 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.TypeSet$2 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:38 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.TypeSet : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:49 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.util.XSFunctionFilter : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:50:59 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.visitor.XSTermFunctionWithParam : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:51:10 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.visitor.XSWildcardVisitor : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:51:21 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
Warnung: Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.xml.internal.xsom.XmlString$1 : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Apr 27, 2014 10:51:33 AM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry
```

I already tried to increase the available memory, however this didn't help:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1G"
```

Any ideas?

Here are the poms (there are modules in this project):

[pom_main.xml](https://gist.github.com/stoefln/11349816)

[pom_sub.xml](https://gist.github.com/stoefln/11349887)

Comment: There should be cross injection which causes infinite bean injection in your beans.

Comment: What happens if you use another DI than weld. Maybe it is a weld specific bug?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to have a perm space bigger than the heap? I actually thought perm space is part of the heap, but not sure about this. 512M heap is not much for an modern app server I'd say. Maybe you try putting a little bit more here.

Comment: @erencan removed all "Inject" annotations, so there shouldnt be any circular injections happening.

Comment: I think they are all warnings. do you get any specific exception?

Comment: @erencan yes, at some point the program throws an OutOfMemory Exception, but it doesnt quit. My machine is running hot: 160% cpu usage. The process is consuming 600MB of RAM..

Comment: When I am providing more memory, it goes up to 1.4G. It really looks like there is some recursion in there (also because of the CPU usage). But I don't know where this might occur

Comment: Please add your `beans.xml` to the question. Are you deploying as WAR?

Comment: @unwichtich I am using an empty beans.xml. And, to be host, I don't know whether a war is created. I don't think so, since I don't have any web-stuff in the project. Only beans for remote access. Sorry, glassfish, e beans,... is quite new to me.

Comment: @baba sorry I would not know how to do that...

Comment: Then please add your `pom.xml` if you have one :)